How can I use Python to do screen controls like Rectangle on the Mac?
I've been using PyObjC to adjust the screen on my Mac, but when I looked at Apple's developer documentation, APIs like setFrame didn't work.
I need to adjust the window of an existing running process, not the screen of a new window.
I'm currently running in VSCode and I'm on a Mac.
This is my code:
resize_window(app_pid, new_size)
            
            print(f"{app_name} window has been moved and resized.")
            return

    print(f"Could not find {app_name} window.")

def move_window(app_pid, new_pos):
    """Move the window to a new position."""
    app = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier_(app_pid)
    # app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
    for window in NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows():
        if window.isVisible():
            window.setFrameTopLeftPoint_(new_pos)

def resize_window(app_pid, new_size):
    """Resize the window."""
    app = NSRunningApplication.runningApplicationWithProcessIdentifier_(app_pid)
    # app.activateWithOptions_(NSApplicationActivateIgnoringOtherApps)
    for window in NSApplication.sharedApplication().windows():
        if window.isVisible():
            frame = window.frame()
            frame.size = new_size
            window.setFrame_display_(frame, True)

# Example usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app_name = "Finder"  # Name of the app to control
    x, y = 100, 100  # New position of the window
    width, height = 800, 600  # New size of the window

    move_and_resize_window(app_name, x, y, width, height)

